# Jhipster Lite 0.29 locally run; Button/Command Apply New/Apply Selected leads to Error-Message Modules not applied

Tags: jhipster

I cloned JHipster Lite from Github.Build and Starting worked but when i try to select some Modules
under http://localhost:7471/landscape i got following Exception in my console:

2023-03-24T19:16:09.645Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-7471-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TranslationBundleLoadingException: Loading of translation bundle failed for [org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, en]] with root cause

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, locale en
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1280)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.TranslationBundle.load(TranslationBundle.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.GlobalBundleCache.lookupBundle(GlobalBundleCache.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.get(NLS.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.getBundleFor(NLS.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText.get(JGitText.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.allValuesOf(Config.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.getEnum(Config.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.(RefDirectory.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.(FileRepository.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:625)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:101)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.secondary.git.JGitGitRepository.init(JGitGitRepository.java:34)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.secondary.git.JGitGitRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.init()
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.domain.JHipsterModulesApplyer.commitIfNeeded(JHipsterModulesApplyer.java:80)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.domain.JHipsterModulesApplyer.apply(JHipsterModulesApplyer.java:71)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.domain.JHipsterModulesApplyer.apply(JHipsterModulesApplyer.java:35)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.application.JHipsterModulesApplicationService.apply(JHipsterModulesApplicationService.java:38)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.primary.ModulesResource.applyPatches(ModulesResource.java:55)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)

2023-03-24T19:16:35.807Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-7471-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TranslationBundleLoadingException: Loading of translation bundle failed for [org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, en]] with root cause

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, locale en
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1280)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.TranslationBundle.load(TranslationBundle.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.GlobalBundleCache.lookupBundle(GlobalBundleCache.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.get(NLS.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.getBundleFor(NLS.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText.get(JGitText.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.allValuesOf(Config.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.getEnum(Config.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.(RefDirectory.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.(FileRepository.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:625)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:101)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.secondary.git.JGitGitRepository.init(JGitGitRepository.java:34)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)

Thank you for help

I cloned JHipster Lite from Github.Build and Starting worked but when i try to select some Modules
under http://localhost:7471/landscape i got following Exception in my console:

2023-03-24T19:16:09.645Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-7471-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TranslationBundleLoadingException: Loading of translation bundle failed for [org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, en]] with root cause

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, locale en
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1280)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.TranslationBundle.load(TranslationBundle.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.GlobalBundleCache.lookupBundle(GlobalBundleCache.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.get(NLS.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.getBundleFor(NLS.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText.get(JGitText.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.allValuesOf(Config.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.getEnum(Config.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.(RefDirectory.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.(FileRepository.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:625)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:101)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.secondary.git.JGitGitRepository.init(JGitGitRepository.java:34)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.secondary.git.JGitGitRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.init()
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.domain.JHipsterModulesApplyer.commitIfNeeded(JHipsterModulesApplyer.java:80)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.domain.JHipsterModulesApplyer.apply(JHipsterModulesApplyer.java:71)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.domain.JHipsterModulesApplyer.apply(JHipsterModulesApplyer.java:35)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.application.JHipsterModulesApplicationService.apply(JHipsterModulesApplicationService.java:38)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.primary.ModulesResource.applyPatches(ModulesResource.java:55)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)

2023-03-24T19:16:35.807Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-7471-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TranslationBundleLoadingException: Loading of translation bundle failed for [org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, en]] with root cause

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText, locale en
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1280)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.TranslationBundle.load(TranslationBundle.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.GlobalBundleCache.lookupBundle(GlobalBundleCache.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.get(NLS.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jgit.nls.NLS.getBundleFor(NLS.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.JGitText.get(JGitText.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.allValuesOf(Config.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.getEnum(Config.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.(RefDirectory.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.(FileRepository.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:625)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:101)
at tech.jhipster.lite.module.infrastructure.secondary.git.JGitGitRepository.init(JGitGitRepository.java:34)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)

Comment: Is your folder writeable? Can you disable "commit module application" when applying modules? The error seems related to jgit.

Comment: You are right.I disabled commit module application and it worked. Thank you very much.